# Is there a way to put a dataframe in the same order as another one in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have two dataframes (with 43 variables and 53 rows) from a survey, both have the same values but the rows are ordered in two random different ways.

Also, some rows have the same values as other rows. Here's an example:

```
DT1 <- data.frame(sex = c("M","F","M","M","F"),
                  Age = c(12,67,12,30,67),
                  V1 = c(7,7,6,6,7))

DT2 <- data.frame(sex = c("F","M","F","M","M"),
                  Age = c(67,12,67,12,30),
                  V1 = c(7,6,7,7,6))
```

My question is the following, is there a way to order the second dataframe as the first dataframe?

Comment: I'm probably misinterpreting the question, but how about `DT2 <- DT1`?

Comment: Yes, if they have the same exact data why do you need `DT2` ? Why not just use `DT1` ?

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `match`

```
DT2New <- DT2[match(do.call(paste, DT1), do.call(paste, DT2)),]
row.names(DT2New) <- NULL
identical(DT1, DT2New)
#[1] TRUE
```